# Maximum sum, min length subset

Tags: python, algorithm, computation-theory

I am trying to solve this popular problem:

"Given an integer array, divide the array into two subsets, A and B, while respecting the following conditions.

1. the intersection of A and B is null.
2. the union A and B is equal to the original array.
3. the number of elements in subset A is minimal.
4. the sum of A's elements is greater than the sum of B's elements.

Return the subset A in increasing order, where the sum of A's elements is greater than the sum of B's elements. If more than one subset exists, return the one with the maximal sum."

I found several solutions online but none of them solve it when the test case is `[2,2,2,5]`

I wrote the following code:

```
def subsetA(nums):
    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    subset_a = []
    sum_a = 0
    sum_b = 0

    for num in nums:
        if sum_a <= sum_b:
            sum_a += num
            subset_a.append(num)
        else:
            sum_b += num

    return sorted(subset_a)
```

This solution works for a lot of cases but it doesn't work for the test case I mentioned above.

The answer should be `[2,2,2]`. But i cannot think of any solution that will return that answer.

How can I improve this code?

Comment: also, we talk about "sublists" here, not "subsets", right? Subsets of [2,2,2,5] would be only {2}, {5} and {2,5}.

Comment: If it is [2,5], then it violates condition 1.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is as a linear program with binary variables. Suppose the array is held by the variable arr, where arr<sub>i</sub> is the value of the element at index `i`.

First define the binary variables.

x<sub>i</sub> equals 1 if arr<sub>i</sub> is assigned to A, and equals 0 if it is assigned to B

The objective (function) and constraints are as follows::

min ∑<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub>

subject to:

∑<sub>i</sub>arr<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub> >=
∑<sub>i</sub>arr<sub>i</sub>(1-x<sub>i</sub>) + t

t is a pre-defined tolerance to ensure that a strict inequality is achieved (linear programs cannot have strict inequalities).

Notice that 1-x<sub>i</sub> equals 1 if arr<sub>i</sub> is assigned to B.

The constraint needs to be rearranged as follows.

∑<sub>i</sub>arr<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub> >= (∑<sub>i</sub>arr<sub>i</sub> + t)/2

---

An integer linear programming (ILP) package can then be used to obtain optimal values for the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are using greedy algorithm, it does not guarantee the best solution. If sum of list is reliable, you can apply dynamic programming.

k-th entry of list `a` contains tuple `(last index, number of items to compose sum k)`.

We fill table `a`: for every value `n` from `nums` check `a` entries whether a) sum `k` might be composed with `n` + `k-n` sum  b) number of items for this sum is better than before

Then look for the smallest `number of items` in the second half of the table - it is the best sum for given condition. Then we retrieve used items.

```
def bestsubsetsum(nums):
    l = len(nums)
    S = sum(nums)
    nums.sort()
    a =[(0,l+1)]*(S+1)
    a[0] = (-1,0)

    for j, n in enumerate(nums):
        for k in range(S, n-1,-1):
            if a[k-n][0] and a[k-n][1]+1 < a[k][1]:
                a[k] = (j+1, a[k-n][1]+1)
    #print(a)

    a[0] = (-1, l+1)
    imin = 0
    for k in range(S//2+1,S+1):
        if a[k][1] <= a[imin][1]:
            imin = k
    A = []
    while imin:
        A.insert(0, nums[a[imin][0]-1])
        imin -= nums[a[imin][0]-1]
    return A


print(bestsubsetsum([3,7,12,1]))
print(bestsubsetsum([2,2,2,5]))
print(bestsubsetsum([2,4,3,7,3,7,3]))
print(bestsubsetsum([2,4,3,9,3,7,3]))

>>
[12]
[2, 5]
[4, 7, 7]
[7, 9]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. `print(bestsubsetsum([1,1,1,2]))` returns `[1,2]`. This is wrong, it should retain `[1,1,1,2]`

Comment: No, this is correct solution. 1,2 is the shortest subset with sum larger than rest

Comment: For input `[2,2,2,5]`, subset `a` contains [2,5] and `b` contains [2, 2]. This breaks condition #1. The correct answer should be `a = [2,2,2]` and `b= [5]`.

Comment: It seems that "set" term is used incorrectly , because we cannot build source array from true sets in many cases

Comment: @Jonathan Why should it return [1,1,1,2], why not [1,1,1]?